# How to deal with intermediate additions while paginating a list with Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, pagination, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to create a backend in Spring Data Mongodb. I have the following code which works and I have used the built in methods by extending my repo with the  MongoRepository class:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/nextpost", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public List getNextPosts(@RequestParam int next) {
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(next, 5, new Sort(new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "id")));
    page = repo.findAll(pageable);
    return page.getContent(); 
  }
```

The above code will return the page as per the page number inserted into the "next" variable.

My android frontend however allows for things to be added and deleted from the database and this causes problems with this pagination method. Lets take an example:

1. When my android frontend starts up, it loads the first 5 items by
   calling "getNextPosts" with next = 0.
2. My android frontend also keeps track of the page it is on and
   increments it when the user wants to see more items.
3. Now, we immediately add 5 more items.
4. When I swipe up to fetch the next 5 items, it calls the
   "getNextPosts" method passing the the "next page" value = 1. The app
   will load the
   **same** 5 items originally displayed when the app was started as the 5 "NEW" items I have added just pushed the 5 "OLD" items down in
   the database.

Therefore on the app, we see 15 items comprising of:

5 "NEW" + 5 "OLD" + 5 "OLD"

So if I gave numbers to all my items on my android ListView, I would see:

15

14

13

12

11

// the above would be the new items added

10

9

8

7

6

//the above would be the original items on page 0

10

9

8

7

6

//the above would be still be the original items but now we are on page 1

Does anyone know how one can solve this issue so that when I swipe up, the items would be:

15

14

13

12

11

// the above would be the new items added

10

9

8

7

6

5

//the above would be the original items on page 0

4

3

2

1

0

//the above would be on page 1

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

That's the nature of the beast. Pagination in Spring Data is defined as retrieving a part of the result set *at the time of querying*. Especially for remote communication, that kind of statelessness is usually the best tradeoff between keeping state, keeping connections open, scalability etc.

### Details

The only way to avoid this would be to capture the state of the database at the time of the first access and only work on that. You can actually build this by retrieving all items and page through the data locally.

Of course hardly anyone does this as it easily gets out of hand for larger data volumes. Also, this would bring up other problems like: when do you actually want to see the items introduced in the meantime? So the definition of "correct content" when paginating a list is not distinct.

### Mitigation strategies

If applicable to your scenario you could try to apply a sorting that guarantees new items to be added at the very end and thus basically making this an append-only list. This would naturally sort the most recent items last though, which is contrary to what's needed often times.

If you use the pagination to work down a list of items and process all of them, another approach is to keep track of the identifiers of the items you already have processed. In your particular scenario, you'd be able to detect that the items have already been processed and go on with the next page. This of course only makes sense if you read and process faster than someone else manipulates the list in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to store an insert timestamp into the db for each entry. This enables you to create deterministic pagination queries:

The moment you initialize pagination (querying first page) you restrict items to have an insert timestamp lower equals than now(). You have to save now() as the pagination timestamp for querying more pages in the future. Since newly added items all get an insert timestamp greater than the pagination timestamp those items won't affect existing paginations.

Please keep in mind that new items won't show until you re-initialize pagination by refreshing the pagination timestmap. But you can simply check for the existence of new items by counting the number of items with an insertion timestamp greater than the pagination timestamp and in this case show a refresh button or something like that.

Comment: I think my solution would be close to what you have described here. I would have to manage this on the android side by getting android to save down the last item retrieved from my server. When I need to get the next page, I will have to send the objectID of the last item back to the server and the server will then send back the items that are after the objectID of the last one. It seems so weird that Spring Data methods do not cater for the dynamic databases and the pages built-in functionality seems to only deal with static databases.

Comment: If you cannot modify the underlying database schema, my proposed solution wouldn't work. But if the item IDs are just numbers which get incremented you could use the max id instead of an insert timestamp. You could query the max ID before starting pagination and then restrict the query for pagination to IDs lower equals than the max ID, assuming the ID of newly added items is greater than this max ID.